# Mocking properties using office-addin-mock yields "Error, property was not loaded"

Tags: outlook, jestjs, mocking, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Consider the following `Greeter.tsx` React component:

```tsx
import React from "react";

export const Greeter: React.FC = () => {
  return <p>Hello, {Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName}</p>;
};
```

and the following `Greeter.test.tsx` test suite:

```tsx
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { OfficeMockObject } from "office-addin-mock";
import { Greeter } from "./Greeter";

const mockData = {
  context: {
    mailbox: {
      userProfile: {
        displayName: "John Doe",
      },
    },
  },
};

const officeMock = new OfficeMockObject(mockData);
global.Office = officeMock;

describe("Greeter", () => {
  it("greets the current user", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<Greeter />);

    expect(getByText(/Hello, John Doe/)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

My test fails because the `Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName` property yields the string `Error, property was not loaded`.

Inspecting the mock object further, it looks like my intended value is indeed saved in the mock object but not used.

[image: State of the Office object]

I did some further digging in the `office-addin-mock` module and it seems that a prior sync is needed to set the `this.loaded` property to `true` and therefore assigning `this.valueBeforeLoaded` to `this.value`. Here's an excerpt from the `office-addin-mock` package:

```js
async sync() {
  this.properties.forEach(async (property: OfficeMockObject, key: string) => {
    await property.sync();
    this.updatePropertyCall(key);
  });
  if (this.loaded) {
    this.value = this.valueBeforeLoaded;
  }
}
```

My understanding is that `context.sync` is a concept prevalent in Excel web add-in development, but not Outlook. However, at this point I stopped the investigation as it's probably easier for Microsoft to dig further. Any assistance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting with so many details!
I created an issue of this bug in our repo to track it: [Office-Addin-Scripts Issues](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-Scripts/issues/587)

This is indeed a bug in our code. What is happening is that properties values assigned in the constructor of OfficeMockObject are not working for Outlook.
A workaround, while the solution is not implemented, is to assign the variable value after the constructor:

```
officeMock.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName = "John Doe";
```